# Scala Unix Timestamp to Date

Tags: scala, datetime

I'm trying to get a formatted date object from a unix timestamp using nscala-time in scala. The timestamp comes through Thrift from Node.js which does return a valid timestamp. I've tried multiple ways of trying to convert the timestamp to a `LocalDateTime` or `DateTime`, anything that doesn't return a year of 1970.

`scala
 println(event.uid.toDateTime);`

and I get:

`1970-01-16T11:59:30.603-07:00`

With a timestamp of `1364370603`.

There's little documentation on the time/data libraries for scala. I'm assuming I'm not using the library correctly, any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to multiply the timestamp by 1000. I do not know about nscala-time, but other date/time libraries (Joda?) use milliseconds, while (usually) unix epoch is returned in seconds

Comment: Thanks for the answer. nscala-time is a wrapper around Joda. Multiplying by 1000 returns `1969-12-15T04:24:43.872-07:00`.

Comment: Are you using a long? joda time returns me `2013-03-27T08:50:03.000+01:00` for `1364370603000L` (notice the L; an int will overflow!)

Comment: Thought so. I'm using thrift and used a 32-bit integer for the timestamp and also tried a 64-bit. After trying a static timestamp long, it worked correctly. The problem lies in thrift I guess. Thank you once again.